# Set cluster to false dynamicaly in mapbox gl

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to set cluster to false and update the map in mapbox gl?
I can set it with `map.getSource("source")._options.cluster = false` but as I understand it is private method and anyway nothing changes after all even after

```
map.getSource('icons').setData(collection);
```

Comment: It looks like the only thing you can do to a GeoJSON source is `setData`. Have you tried just `getSource('source').cluster = false` though?